# Can I make Y axis begin at specific value in ChartJS?

Tags: chart.js, vue-chartjs

I have this chart, starting at 0 and I want the Y axis to begin at 20. It surprises me how there is nothing related to this in the official ChartJS docs. Is this possible in any way?

I have tried several ways to do it, eg. with `ticks` or `min` value and so on but nothing worked.

The application is written in `Nuxt3` and the ChartJS library used is `vue-chart-3`.

```
const options = computed(() => ({
  responsive: true,
  plugins: {
    legend: {
      display: false,
    },
    title: {
      display: false,
    }
  },
  scales: {
    x: {
      stacked: true,
    },
    y: {
      stacked: true,
    }
  }
}));

const chartData = computed(() => ({
  labels: ['Provider'],
  datasets: [
    {
      data: [selectedDataset.value?.score.uncustomized],
      backgroundColor: ['#00b7c4'],
    },
    {
      data: [selectedDataset.value?.score.difference],
      backgroundColor: ['#204992'],
    },
  ],
}));

const { barChartProps, barChartRef } = useBarChart({
  chartData,
  options,
});
```

Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Please share your code and version of chart.js you are using because its working fine for me

Comment: I will update my question including what you asked.

Comment: So could you please tell me @LeeLenalee how it is working for you then? What option do you use for the Y axis to make it start at 20 for example instead of 0?
In my honest opinion, sharing code isn't always necessary. Just share a possible solution and I can take it from there on.

Comment: No might not be necessary but if you don't post any code it shows low effort like you didn't try, also you said you tried things, show it it makes spotting an error easyer and shows you tried something

Answer (score 0):

If you want the axis to start at a given number you need to use the `min` property:

```js
const options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        borderColor: 'pink'
      },
      {
        label: '# of Points',
        data: [7, 11, 5, 8, 3, 7],
        borderColor: 'orange'
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      y: {
        min: 6
      }
    }
  }
}

const ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.7.1/chart.js"></script>
</body>
```